# Apache POI - XSSF: Row.getCell()

Tags: apache-poi, xssf

I am using XSSF to access the .xlsx format. Extracting row data and cell data is being done by

```
Row.getCell(1) // to get the first cell data.
```

Is there a way to access cells like

```
Row.getCell(A) or Row.getCell(AC).
```

This will be very helpfull for me to access columns. 
Can any one tell me the way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the main class you're looking for is [CellReference](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html) - it handles converting between user facing references such as "B2" into file format references like row=1,col=1 . There's a static method on there that handles your exact use case, [convertColStringToIndex](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html#convertColStringToIndex%28java.lang.String%29)

For your use case, you'd want code something like

```
 Cell c = row.getCell( CellReference.convertColStringToIndex("G") );
```

Comment: @Rajath Don't you think it's time to set this as the best answer? ;)

Answer (score 3):

The question is regarding reaching out a cell using its references, if I am not wrong.

```
Sheet referenceSheet = workbook.getsheet("Sheet name your intrested in");

CellReference ref = new CellReference("C24");
Row row = referenceSheet.getRow(ref.getRow());
 // null check for the row
if(row != null)
{
Cell cell = row.getCell(ref.getCol());
}
```

In this way we can refer a cell using its reference.